# What does exactly mean the power specified in a speaker datasheet?

Tags: amplifier, speakers

I'm making my own guitar tube amp, based on a Fender 5e3 project. The nominal power of the amp is around 15W. Next step would be to choose a speaker, that I already did, the speaker is a 12 inches (8 Ohms) Eminence Legend.

The issue is: On the speaker datasheet says nominal power of 75W, what is exactly that power? Is how much power can be dissipated by the speaker, or is the some kind of equivalent sound power emited by the speaker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power is the maximum electrical [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28physics%29) the speaker can handle without damage. It has only a rough correlation with acoustic power output: some (perhaps even most) of the electrical power also goes into losses in the speaker coil, magnetic losses, friction losses, and so on.

If the speaker is rated for a higher power than your amplifier, that's good. It means it can take all the amplifier can dish out without damage. If the speaker is rated for less, then your amplifier at full volume may damage the speaker, and usually that's bad.

Beware that cheap speakers tend to use meaningless methods to arrive at their power rating, like the peak power they can take at the very peak of a cycle, instead of the average power of the AC being fed to them. When you see those $5 "100W" computer speakers that sound too good (the price, not the quality) to be true, that's what's going on. Your speaker sounds legit, however.

Further reading: [audio power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_power) at Wikipedia.

Comment: There are some common reasons that you might want an amp to be able to provide more power than the speaker is rated for-- sometimes several times more.  It has to do with "fudge factors" in the specs (peak vs. RMS) and the systems ability to handle transient loads effectively.  But this does make it possible to blow up the speakers by driving them too hard.

Comment: I wish there were a standard practice to rate speakers for(1) how much power would be required to permanently damage the speaker in one second or less; (2) how much power can the speaker output for an hour or more without damage; (3) how much power can the speaker output while meeting its THD specs (assume, in each case, the waveform which would yield the worst-case performance).  All three numbers would be useful to know, but rarely are they cleanly labeled.